# mysql php Relate tables between (migrated) full tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm having an issue relating tables. Long story short I'm migrating tables from a Postgres DB to a mysql one. Since I'm using Laravel, Eloquent has made it easy to migrate the tables "users" and "groups" because they are also objects, so all I did was convert the postgres result to Json, adding each element and saving it to the laravel's mysql DB. 
There's a many-to-many relationship between users and groups. Postgres also contains a "user-group" table with this relation. And I've managed to keep the same id's from postgres. But the code to save it to mysql is slightly different from before (saving users and groups). Here's what I'm doing:

```
foreach ($jsonData as $rel) {
    DB::table('group_user')->insert(array(
        array('user_id' => $rel['user_id']),
        array('group_id' => $rel['group_id']),
    ));
}
```

The DB format is pretty much the same in both databases.
The only difference is that group_user has his own auto-incrementing id alongside with the foreign keys for user_id and group_id

Trying to run the function mentioned above turns this result.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a
child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ProjectName`.`group_user`, 
CONSTRAINT `group_user_group_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES
`groups` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `group_user` (`user_id`) values (1), (1))
```

I don't understand why, there's a user with id 1 and a group also with id 1. The table is fully functional in the postgres DB. My fear is that I'm establishing a relation with already existing data, and that might be what's causing these issues.
Thank you for your time and patience.

EDIT: the corrected query goes like this btw

```
foreach ($jsonData as $rel) {
    DB::table('group_user')->insert(array(
        array('user_id' => $rel['user_id'], 'group_id' => $rel['group_id']),
    ));
}
```

Thank you very much @Mark B

Comment: your query is wrong. it should be `values (1,1)`. right now you're doing the equivalent of `values (1,null), (1,null)`

Comment: ahhh... so that query adds multiple entries to the database simultaneously, right? What's the correct synthax then? Thank you for pointing that out @MarcB

Comment: what you've got is mysql's extended syntax. `insert into sometable (field) values (value1), (value2), (value3)` inserts 3 records. e.g. each set of `()` is another set of values for a new record. `insert ... values (1,1)` inserts two values into one record (since there's just one set of `()`).

Comment: you were right @MarcB, the query was inserting (1, null) and (1,null). I changed it so it would add (1,1). Thank you very much. Now I'm struggling with another problem. the original group_user table has 2000+ entries, copying all of those and inserting them into the new db took so long that php timed out. I already edited php.ini, luckly this is a one time operation so I don't have to worry much about optimization.

Comment: there is `insert into ... select from ...`, which you can use to copy stuff from one table to another in a single query, rather than a pile of loops with separate select+insert operations..

Comment: @MarcB even if it's from postgres to mysql? Doesn't my method bear some advantage because Eloquent can create all the objects? (or does this not affect anything at all)

Comment: if nothing else, you could export the table as csv or whatever from PG, then load that into mysql. plenty of ways of transferring data betweeen disparate DBs, and not all of them require big scripts to transfer row-by-row.

Comment: @MarcB this way seems feasible enough. For the time being it worked. I'll look up ways to optimize this when I finish the rest of the work ;) Thank you very much for the help.